# Word whose form is contrary to its meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a word whose form is contrary to its meaning?

For example, "quotidian" is anything but quotidian.

Comment: Duplicate of [Is there a term for a word that defeats its own purpose?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23581/is-there-a-term-for-a-word-that-defeats-its-own-purpose) and [What is a catchy word that means (non-)self-descriptive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11422/what-is-a-catchy-word-that-means-non-self-descriptive)

Comment: I'd argue that my question is more specific than the first and different than the second, though it's true that heterological is offered as an answer in both.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My apologies to Professor Lawler, but I'm fairly sure that the word you want is [heterological](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/heterological).

Comment: +1 You're right. Lawler's citation reads in relevant part: "a predicate is *heterological* if it is *not* true of itself, that is, if it does *not* itself have the property it expresses". [*emphasis added*]

Comment: No apologies necessary. I'm happy I recognized it as referring to Russell's Paradox.

Comment: True, but for the benefit of future visitors to this page, it should be noted that this is not a word in general circulation. It is a contrived word that is used only to illustrate Russell's Paradox.

Answer (score 4):

Another term is *Non-heterological*. This has featured in many discussions of [Russell's Paradox](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/self-reference/).

Comment: Your source is good but it seems like "heterological" was the word I'm looking for.

Comment: Quite right. Those binary distinctions that lead to paradoxes do so for a reason. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The term is *[ironic](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/american-english/ironic_1)*

> using words that suggest the opposite of what you intend, usually in order to be humorous

The term also could be called *[oxymoronic](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/oxymoron?view=uk)*

> a figure of speech in which apparently contradictory terms appear in conjunction (e.g. faith unfaithful kept him falsely true).

While oxymorons usually involve multiple words, the contradictory nature seems to fit.

Comment: I guess irony would cover it if you were calling attention to the heterological nature of the word. ("German isn't German. Think about that.") However, I'm speaking more generally. And oxymoron, at least from your quoted definition, requires a "conjunction of terms", which I would think implies more than one. (Always, not just usually).