# Is there a word for Words that describe themselves or a word for words that do the opposite

Tags: single-word-requests

**Self Describing Example:** sesquipedalian is a sesquipedalian word
**Opposite Example:** quotidian is not a quotidian word (obviously just my opinion)

Comment: @ermanen I agree that the first part is a duplicate, but what about the second?

Comment: @bib: The second question is a dupe also: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/86841/word-whose-form-is-contrary-to-its-meaning/86849#86849

Comment: @ermanen Thanks. Maybe it should also be listed in the body. (I searched for *oxymoronic*, but Prof. Lawlor has now elucidated me.)

Comment: Thanks for the references to autological/homological/autonym and heterological. Sorry about the dupe. I actually couldn't see how to search the site (now I see the box up at the top). But I figured once I typed the question I would see if it was a dupe. I clicked on all the links but none of them led me to the already asked question so I posted. Should have know better. I also like that the referenced dupe was itself a dupe.